# migrating from apache, need help on some rewrite rules

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, nginx

I need some help to convert some apache rewrite rules to nginx,

here is the apache version:

```
<Location ^/mywebapp>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
  Allow from 10.10.0.0/16
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app_dev\.php/.*
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !app\.php$
  RewriteRule (.*) app.php [QSA,L]
</Location>
```

here is what I have in nginx:

```
location ~ ^/mywebapp {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  allow 192.168.0.0/16;
  allow 10.10.0.0/16;
  deny all;

  location ~ app_dev\.php/.* { }
  location ~ app\.php$ { }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ app.php break;
  }
}
```

which does not work as intended. Can someone point me where I'm wrong ?

Comment: What *does* happen, then, if you run in with that and try to access `/mywebapp` or `/mywebapp/foo`?

Comment: In apache I get redirected to another page and on nginx I get 404

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be able to replace the whole rewrite bit (i.e. starting with app_dev location) with

```
try_files $uri app.php$is_args$args
```

and should be fine.

Comment: I still don't get redirected with the following `location ~ ^/mywebapp {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    allow 10.10.0.0/16;
    deny all;

    try_files $uri app.php$is_args$args;

}`